# Navigate in timeline to a specific year/month AND post (facebookID) with a single url

Tags: anchor, facebook-timeline, facebook-ui

I noticed that with a URL of the format

> facebook.com/*username*/timeline/2013/4

we move to the end of the specified month of the year.

Now I need to use an url to navigate a user in my timeline to a specific post (facebookID) in a way that he can still move up and down on timeline from this point of time (anchor).

Any clues?

Comment: (Unfortunately, navigating to a specific day 

is apparently not possible (anymore?): https://www.facebook.com/wdmacaskill/timeline/2014/7/16 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a Facebook page, each post's HTML element has its own unique HTML `id`.
You can make use of this fact to directly link to a post within a page on Facebook by identifying the post's `id` and using it as the [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) in the URL.

<sub>To find a post's HTML element `id`, right click the particular post in your browser [I'm assuming Chrome], then click "inspect element". In the opened development environment, find  an enclosing `div` of the inspected element which contains an `id` HTML attribute.</sub>

For example, a link to a particular post on Disney's March 2013 Facebook timeline is the following:

https://www.facebook.com/Disney/timeline/2013/02/#tl_unit_6154529015953642023

Comment: The [Show Anchors bookmarklet](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2009/12/show-anchors-bookmarklet.html) is an arguably more convenient alternative to inspecting the HTML source.